# Openshift: Deployments with Rolling Strategy and Persistent Volume(RWO) tends to Fail

Tags: openshift-origin

I have deployed a django application openshift, provided as PaaS by a company to us. I have added Persistent Volume with this deployment with is RWO(Read Write Once). I don't use that volume elsewhere. The deployment uses Rolling Strategy.

When I try to deploy a new build, it hangs for more than 5 minutes and later it fails. But when I tested in Minishift in my OSX, it does not cause any problem. I am confused, is it a normal issue for Rolling strategy to get fail for Persistent Volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that PaaS is a multiregion one (like ie. multiple AWS AZs) then it is possible your pod was rescheduled on a node in different AZ and hence it was unable to mount the same block device that was initially scheduled in a different zone.

Comment: As far as I know, its not multiregional. I had a discussion with their developers(PaaS providers), and they said, for Persistent volume(RWO), it can not mount from one pod to another in Rolling deployment process, and Pods are from same build. But I am not seeing same behavior in my local machine.

Comment: local machine is easy cause minikube has these PVs as hostPath, so they are fast and simple. If your pod gets terminated it should free the PVC (I assume you do use PVC and PV) and the new one should be able to reuse it, but well, it really can depend on a lot of things